# Xcode 12 - SwiftUI - Array of Strings into Buttons

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, button, swiftui

I am trying to make an app using Xcode 12 in Swift. Right now, I have listed an array of strings with a functioning search bar. I want to turn these strings into buttons, so the user can select one and bring them to the next page of the app. This is my code so far:

```
    @State var searchText = ""
    @State var isSearching = false
    let languages = ["Arabic", "Chinese", "Dutch", "English", "French", "German", "Greek", "Hawaiian", "Hebrew", "Japanese", "Korean", "Polish", "Russian", "Spanish", "Italian"]
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView {
                HStack {
                    HStack {
                        TextField("Search", text: $searchText).ignoresSafeArea()
                            .padding(.leading, 30)
                    }
                    .padding(10)
                    .background(Color(.systemGray5))
                    .cornerRadius(20)
                    .padding(.horizontal, 10)
                    .onTapGesture (perform: {
                        isSearching = true
                    })
                    .overlay(
                        HStack {
                            Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass")
                            Spacer()
                        }.padding(.horizontal, 28)
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    ).transition(.move(edge: .trailing))
                    .animation(.easeIn)
                    if isSearching {
                        Button(action: {
                            isSearching = false
                            searchText = ""
  UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil) 
                        }, label: {
                            Text("Cancel")
                                .padding(.trailing)
                                .padding(.leading, -12)
                        })
                        .transition(.move(edge: .trailing))
                        .animation(.easeIn)
                    }
                }
                //ForEach(self.languages, id: \.self) { language in
                ForEach(self.languages.filter {
                    self.searchText.isEmpty ? true : $0.contains(self.searchText)
                }, id: \.self) { language in
                    HStack{
                    Text(language)
                    Spacer()
                }.padding()
                Divider()
                    .background(Color(.systemGray4))
                    .padding(.leading)
                }
                }
            .navigationTitle("Language")
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where did you got stuck? Or, what's the problem with your code?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using a `NavigationLink`:

```
ForEach(self.languages.filter { self.searchText.isEmpty ? true : $0.contains(self.searchText) }, id: \.self) { language in
    NavigationLink(destination: //YourView) {
        HStack{
            Text(language)
                Spacer()
        }.padding()
        Divider()
            .background(Color(.systemGray4))
            .padding(.leading)
    }
}
```

or if you wanna ditch the navigation, use a `.fullScreenCover`:

```
ForEach(self.languages.filter { self.searchText.isEmpty ? true : $0.contains(self.searchText) }, id: \.self) { language in
    Button(action: {
        present.toggle() //declare a new Boolean variable
    }) {
        HStack{
            Text(language)
                Spacer()
        }.padding()
        Divider()
            .background(Color(.systemGray4))
            .padding(.leading)
    }
}.fullScreenCover(isPresented: $present) {
    //YourView
}
```

Comment: Is there also a way for the program to remember which item in the array was pressed in order to switch views using the NavigationLink. I need it to be able to do this in order to work on the next part of my app.

Comment: Yess you can pass the item to the next view, you just need to declare a variable like so: var item: String and: NavigationLink(destination: YourView(item: language))

Comment: I tried that and I am getting a few errors. Also, changing the views with NavigationLink is not working. For some reason I am able to use a navigation link to view a screen with set text, but when I try to use it to change the actual view it gives me an error

Comment: Maybe I am not using the Navigation Link correctly to display a new view. This is my code:                                    
         ForEach(self.languages.filter {
                self.searchText.isEmpty ? true : 
                    $0.contains(self.searchText)
           }, id: \.self) { language in
                        Divider()
                        .padding()
                        NavigationLink(destination: Text ("CameraView")) {
                            HStack{
                                Text(language).foregroundColor(.black)
                        }

Comment: Okay your code will let you navigate to a view displaying a text: camera view. If you wanna navigate to a view, replace Text(“CameraView”) with CameraView